# Queuing for Heroic Burning Crusade in WoW Dungeon FInder

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I started playing WoW again after 10 or so years and the Dungeon Finder is kind of new to me, so help me out. I'm level 80. I can use the Dungeon Finder to queue for Burning Crusade Normal, Wrath of the Lich King Normal and WotLK Heroic... but I can't queue for Burning Crusade Heroic. Why not? I want to run a Heroic BC dungeon to build some rep, but the BC Heroic section doesn't even show up in my options.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You only get to see the dungeons within your level range. If you exceed the max level of that dungeon they will disappear from the dungeon browser. Heroic dungeons have a stricter level requirement than normal dungeons (max and min level), so they disappear sooner.

In your case you have reached the range of WOTLK and only get to see the heroics from there. And you're too high for BC and too low for cata heroics, so they're not there. You can still access lower heroic dungeons by going there directly, but not queue for them on your own`*`.

Some examples:

Level 90

[image: level 90 ui]

Level 110

[image: level 110 ui]

---

`*` - You *CAN* join the other dungeons.

1. Go there directly. Just walk in and you can clear them (solo or with a pre made group).
2. Group up with someone within qualified level range (e.g. level 70 for BC heroics) and start a [**party sync**](https://worldofwarcraft.com/en-us/news/23151436/party-sync-preview). Let them queue up for a dungeon and you can join them. The dungeon will be scaled to match your level (wihtout affecting the other people) and you won't be able to use skills, talents, etc higher than allowed by the dungeon, so you should feel perfectly like you're in a "real" dungeon. Due to the low amount of people doing this you have to expect longer waiting times.
3. Time walking weekly events work as well. They basically eliminate the max level requirement. If a certain event is up you can queue for it and it will be exactly like the heroic version of those dungeons, except that you have all your current skills and spells available. Higher gear will be scaled down to match the level of the dungeon, so they can't be outgeared that easily.

Comment: Option 2 is almost not worth mentioning since the only people in the dungeon queue for a heroic dungeon before the current max level are going to be you and your friend, so you'll never actually get a dungeon group.  If you really want to do something like that you'd need to put together a full group yourself.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I agree. Depending on the content it's very rare to get a random heroic group together, but if you have a tank with you it's still an option. The higher the dungeon level the better the chances.

Comment: It doesn't make -any- sense to me that the Heroics drop off of the list before the normals do. I believe you, but it just doesn't make any sense. 10 years ago (or whenever it was) we were running BC Heroics at level 80. That was the normal. You didn't do heroics until you were at the max level for that area, so if I can do normals at 80, it makes no sense I can't do heroics at 80. I wanted to get Consortium rep, but it only works in Heroic Mana-Tombs at Honored. :(

Comment: @KennyWyland I'm not sure why Blizzard takes some heroics off the list sooner than others. This is not always the case. As for rep farming there are easier ways. You don't even have to have them all on one character in order to get the achievement for x reps on exalted. The easiest way is going in there to solo the dungeon. And another way is the time walking event. During that event you can even purchase [rep tokens](https://www.wowhead.com/item=129945/commendation-of-the-consortium). The only problem is there is only one time walking week per month and they cycle through the expansions.